# Register to Google Cloud Messaging from outside of the app

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

Is it possible to sign up the app for GCM from outside and receive the `registration_id` having all the information needed?
I mean I could send the environmental variables to the server side which would register to GCM for me, so that I can avoid dealing with these requests on the client-side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible. The Registration ID that you get from GCM is tied to an application on a specific device. If you would try to perform the registration from the server, how would GCM know to identify the device that the Registration ID is tied to?

Comment: I could provide the device_id, android_id and whatever's needed to the server. I guess the registration is done by regular TCP/IP request? So maybe I could peek into the source of `GoogleCloudMessaging#register` and see how it's done?

Comment: No, it cannot be done. It's not the app which handles GCM **directly**. It's framework (or Google Play Services to be exact).

Comment: Yeah I know, but I thought it's a public API. Fair enough then, thank you!